# Diagonal Query in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am dealing with a table that has roughly 50k rows, each of which containing a timestamp and an array of smallints of the length 25920. What I am trying to do is pull a single value from each array with a list of timestamps that is being passed. For example, I would have 25920 timestamps that I would pass and I would want the first element for the timestamp, then the second element for the second timestamp and so on. By now I am having a tunnel vision and do not seem to find a solution to what is probably a trivial problem.

I either end up pulling the full 25920 rows which consumes too much memory or execute 25920 queries that take way too long for obvious reasons.

I am using Python 3.8 with the psycopg2 module.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate an index into the array for every row you extract with your query. In this specific case (diagonal) you want an index based on the row number. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT ts, val[row_number() over (order by ts)] FROM ... ORDER BY ts
```

Comment: And there it is, simple and efficient. Thank you very much for the quick response. Your line of code does exactly what I needed. I cannot upvote your answer since I lack the 15 reputation.